# Sump pump running continuously, float switch ok

Tags: sump-pump

I have a sump pump in the crawl space of my house, with a French drain system. Several years ago the pump failed and I replaced it. Yesterday I realized the pump was running continuously - it’s not loud or obvious, but took us a while to realize what the motor sound was. The location is not easy to get to to check it or work on it.

We have had only light rain, and the water level in the pit was below the intake, and everything around it seemed dry.

I unplugged it and plugged it back in and it did not restart. I manually moved the float switch a few times. The pump turned on and off appropriately, and the float mode smoothly with no obstruction.

This afternoon I could again hear the pump running continuously. Since it was easier to access I tripped the GFI in the garage and reset it, the pump again did not restart.

Is there is something I can check or fix without replacing the whole unit?

Edit: The pump is an Everbilt pump and the float switch has the direct-in connection. I believe the float switch has a magnetic sensor, but I can't find the same type of switch. It looks like I might be able to get a replacement tether-type float switch.

Answer (score 1):

The float switch has failed. Replace it.  Good Luck.